# expected nested-name-specifier before 'sktraits'

Tags: c++, traits

This is a snippet of a class template which is causing compilation errors:

```
/* Secondary index class */
template<class TKey, class TVal, class key_traits, class val_traits>
template<class TSecKey, class sktraits> 
class CBtreeDb<TKey, TVal, key_traits, val_traits>::CDbSecondaryIndex: protected CBtreeDb<TKey, TVal>, public IDeallocateKey
{
public:
 typedef TSecKey           skey_type;
 typedef typename sktraits                         skey_traits;
 typedef CNewDbt<TSecKey, sktraits>                CDbSKey;
 typedef typename iterator_t<TSecKey, skey_traits> iterator;
 typedef typename iter_lower_bound_t<skey_type>    iter_lower_bound;
 typedef typename iter_upper_bound_t<skey_type>    iter_upper_bound;

 CDbSecondaryIndex(CDbEnv* pEnv, u_int32_t flags, bool bAllowDuplicates=false):
  CBtreeDb(pEnv, flags, bAllowDuplicates)
 {

 }

    // Class implementation continues ...
};
```

The compiler error message I get is:

```
expected nested-name-specifier before 'sktraits'.
```

Actually, this error occurs on every `typedef` declaration followed by `typename`

I have compiled this code succesfully in the past using VS2005 and VS2008 on XP.

I am currently building on Ubuntu 9.10, using gcc 4.4.1

I looked this error up on Google and it appears that the `typename` isn't necessary on the line (where the error occurs), because the standard assumption is that an identifier in that position is a type. g++ seems to be complaining because it expects any `typename` declaration there to be qualified (i.e. A::B).

Is this is a correct diagnosis of the problem - if so, then how do I "fully qualify" the `typename`?

In short, how may I resolve this problem?

Comment: I managed to fix this (i.e. get the code to compile) - by simply removing the 'typename' that follows the typdef decl. 
 Although the header compiles successfully now, I am still not satisfied because I want to know the underlying (i.e. technical reason) why I had to remove typename (especially, when similar notation is used in the STL classes)

Answer (score 7):

`typename` is needed to specify that a **dependent** name is in fact a type. Your names are not dependent names, so no `typename` is required or allowed.

**Update** The standard actually has this syntax definition:

> *typename-speciﬁer*:
>     **typename** *nested-name-speciﬁer identiﬁer*
>     **typename** *nested-name-speciﬁer* **template**<sub>*opt*</sub> *simple-template-id*

The two other places you can use the typename keyword are in the template parameter list and in the `using` declaration (in the latter case it too must be followed by a nested name specifier).

Answer (score 1):

The following is not allowed:

```
template<class A>
template<class B> class F { ... };
```

You can have at most one `template<>` specification before a class/function definition.

Comment: Please explain. Comeau people disagree: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#outsidedef -- I have no standard handy but Comeau is pretty reliable wrt standards compliance.

Comment: The standard says in 14.5.2/1:  "A member template of a class template that is deﬁned outside of its class template definition shall be specified with the template-parameters of the class template followed by the template-parameters of the member template", and gives an example: `template<class T> template<class T2> int string<T>::compare(const T2& s)`.